# add auto number in server side data table laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, serverside-javascript

I want to add auto number for my table like 1,2,3 until record end.

I use ($no + 1) which I usually use not work.

for load data work fine, But I dont know how to add auto numer
please help me,

this for my Controller

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{

  $columns = array(
      0 => 'auto_num',
      1 => 'add_time',
      2 => 'id'
    );

    $totalData = DataTes::count();
    $limit = $request->input('length');
    $start = $request->input('start');
    $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
    $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

    if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){
        $posts = DataTes::offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                ->get();
        $totalFiltered = DataTes::count();
    }else{
        $search = $request->input('search.value');
        $posts = DataTes::where('auto_num', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('add_time','like',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('id','like',"%{$search}%")
                        ->offset($start)
                        ->limit($limit)
                        ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                        ->get();
        $totalFiltered = DataTes::where('auto_num', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('add_time','like',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('id','like',"%{$search}%")
                        ->count();
    }


    $data = array();

    if($posts){
        $counter = 1;
        foreach($posts as $r){
            $nestedData['auto_num'] = $r->auto_num;
            $nestedData['add_time'] = $r->add_time;
            $nestedData['id'] = $r->id;
            $nestedData['no'] = $counter;
            $data[] = $nestedData;
            $counter++;
        }
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "draw"          => intval($request->input('draw')),
        "recordsTotal"  => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data"          => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);


}
```

and this for my js

```
    $('#example1').DataTable( {
    "ordering": true,
    'autoWidth': true,

            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url":"<?= route('dataProcessing') ?>",
                "dataType":"json",
                "type":"POST",
                "data":{"_token":"<?= csrf_token() ?>"}
            },
            "columns":[
      {"data": "auto_num"},
      {"data": "add_time"},
      {"data": "id"},
      {"data": "no"}
            ]
        } );
```

I hope you can understand what I mean
sorry for my bad english, I use laravel v5.6

Comment: read about incrementing variable

Comment: @hungrykoala I now, but how I implement to server side data table, I always get error

Comment: `$nestedData['auto_num'] = $r->auto_num;` is this the one that you want to auto increment?

Comment: no, in my code dont any have auto_num, I dont want to auto numbering from database, but just show to view how much I data I Have, I just show my code and someone please add if know what I want @hungrykoala

Comment: I mean is that the line of your code where you want to have the auto increment? Since that line is in your code.

Comment: I want to add column "No" in my table, and that column just number 1,2,3 -- End, that will increase or decrease automatic based on how much data in database, but this number not from database, just number to show how much data I have in table @hungrykoala

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if($posts){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($posts as $r){
       $nestedData['auto_num'] = $r->auto_num;
       $nestedData['add_time'] = $r->add_time;
       $nestedData['id'] = $r->id;
       $nestedData['no'] = $counter;
       $data[] = $nestedData;
       $counter++;
   }
}

  {"data": "auto_num"},
  {"data": "add_time"},
  {"data": "id"},
  {"data": "no"}
```

Don't forget to add the "No" in your table header.

Comment: still get error, I update my question like you said, and I try in mw  Project still get error `DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: did you update your table as well? you'll need to have a new column there for your "No" post your html in your question

Comment: yupz, but data still not coming out @hungrykoala

Comment: I have another problem, previous problem I can fix it, new problem is, just only 1-10, if I next to the page not continue to 11-20 but repeated to 1-10

Comment: That is weird. Can you try and do this `echo json_encode($json_data); die;` and see the network logs to see your JSON value if it is as expected?

Comment: no, are you have been try that code ? the number just repeated only 1-10